# Select tag with array as value, how to choose array item 1 vs item 2 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I have a select tag with options that need to have two values assigned to them like so.

```
<select id="industry_churn" class="form-control">
                        <option value="0">Select a Value</option>
                        <option value="{.70, .05}">Salon/Barber</option>
                        <option value="{.95, .05}">Painting</option>
                    </select>
```

On the JavaScript side of things, I have the following function that makes multiple calculations:

```
function calculateAll() {
var averageJobs = +document.getElementById("averageJobs").value;
var jobValue = +document.getElementById("jobValue").value;
var yearsOpen = +document.getElementById("yearsOpen").value;
var industry_churn = +document.getElementById("industry_churn").value; /* array item 1 */
var recovery = +document.getElementById("industry_churn").value; /* array item 2 */

var inactive = (averageJobs * 50) * yearsOpen * industry_churn; /* Value 1 */
var missedRevenue = inactive * jobValue;
var jobsRecovered = (averageJobs * 50) * recovery * yearsOpen; /* Value 2 */
var revenueYear = jobsRecovered * jobValue;


document.getElementById("inactive").value = inactive;
document.getElementById("missedRevenue").value = missedRevenue;
document.getElementById("jobsRecovered").value = jobsRecovered;
document.getElementById("revenueYear").value = revenueYear;
```

}

The variable **missedRevenue** needs to pull **item 1(industry_churn)** from the option tag and the variable **jobsRecovered** needs to pull **item 2(recovery)** from the option tag.

How can I get my JavaScript to pull the values from the array?

Comment: You can have the same attribute more than once on any element. You may want to use custom data attributes instead (e.g. `data-val1 data-val2`). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: just make an array with objects and val1/val2 are the properties of those :)

Comment: You can't have with duplicate attributes.

Comment: An option is also to store values into comma-separated strings, and then split them to arrays in JS ... Or just store values as JSON (like `value="[0.7, 0.05]"`), and parse those JSON strings to arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of your `value` attribute needs to be like that (`"{.70, .05}"`), then you could use `match` to turn that value into an array:

```
var arr = document.getElementById("industry_churn").value.match(/[\d\.]+/g).map(Number);
var industry_churn = arr[0];
var recovery = arr[1];
```

If however you have control over how the data is attached to the `option` tags, then consider setting the values to a JSON text:

```
<select id="industry_churn" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Select a Value</option>
    <option value="[0.70, 0.05]">Salon/Barber</option>
    <option value="[0.95, 0.05]">Painting</option>
</select>
```

and then:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("industry_churn").value);
var industry_churn = arr[0];
var recovery = arr[1];
```

Note that with ES6 you can use the destructuring assignment syntax:

```
var [industry_churn,recovery]=JSON.parse(document.getElementById("industry_churn").value)
```